# How do I display what specific vowels are in the word

Tags: python

I have finished almost everything in my homework program. The last feature is getting the program to display the specific vowels that were found in the input.  For example:

```
Please enter a word: look
The vowels in your word are 
o
o
there were 2 vowels
I'm terribly sorry if I missed any 'y's.
```

Code:

```
def main():
    vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    count = 0
    string = input(str("please enter a word:"))
    for i in string:
        if i in vowels:
            count += 1

    print("The vowels in your word are:")

    print("There were",count,"vowels")
    print("Sorry if I missed any 'y's")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Well, you have access to each vowel at the right moment, why not print them?

Comment: You've got two options: 1) print the vowels as you find them (in the loop) or 2) collect them in a list and print them later.

Comment: Try to change vowels to a dictionary mapping from a vowel to number of occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

All you're missing is to keep a string of the vowels as you find them.  This is a lot like counting the vowels.  Start it at the "base value" of a string, the empty string.  Every time you find a vowel, add (concatenate it) to your string.  For instance:

```
vowels_found = ""
for i in string:
    if i in vowels:
        vowels_found += i
print(vowels_found)
print(len(vowels_found))
```

After this, print `vowels_found` just where you planned.  If you want them on separate lines, as in your posted sample, then print each one *inside* the loop, and don't use `vowels_found` at all.

There are more advanced, more direct ways to do this in python: you can include the filtering in a single statement such that this routine is basically two lines long: one to collect the vowels, the other to count and print them.  Worry about those a little later in the class ... but if someone posts those solutions, pay attention.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a print statement within your `if`. This way when a vowel is found, it is printed in the manner you displayed in your question.

NB you'll need to move your `print("The vowels in your word are:")` to before your `if` so that it is printed before the vowels.

eg

```
def main():
    vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    count = 0
    string = input(str("please enter a word:"))
    print("The vowels in your word are:") #puts text before the vowels printed in `if`
    for i in string:
        if i in vowels:
            count += 1
            print (i) #prints the vowel if it is found



    print("There were",count,"vowels")
    print("Sorry if I missed any 'y's")

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```